# how to prevent secretary from inserting a doctor availability similar to another's doctor of same speciality using sql query?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have a windows form application C# for a medical clinic that a secretary have to use it to insert doctor's avaibilities. I want to prevent the secretary from inserting similar avaibility to another's doctor of same speciality in the same day.

1- I have these tables in my database:
[image: database tables]

2- My windows form is :
[image: Windows Form Application C#]

3- My code is :

```
 private void bt_addDisp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedDoctor = dgv_DispMed.CurrentRow.Index;
        string prenomMed = dgv_DispMed.Rows[selectedDoctor].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        string nomMed = dgv_DispMed.Rows[selectedDoctor].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you realy want to add this disponibility for Dr "+prenomMed+" "+nomMed+" ?", "Confirm Add Disponibility", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            string spec_id = dgv_DispMed.Rows[selectedDoctor].Cells[6].Value.ToString();


            int jr = int.Parse(cmb_day.SelectedValue.ToString());

            string Str_hdeb = cmb_startTime.Text.ToString();
            string Str_hfin = cmb_endTime.Text.ToString();

            string[] tab_hdeb = Str_hdeb.Split(':');
            int hdeb = int.Parse(tab_hdeb[0]);

            string[] tab_hfin = Str_hfin.Split(':');
            int hfin = int.Parse(tab_hfin[0]);

            MySqlConnection c1 = new MySqlConnection();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            c1.ConnectionString = "Database=growing_together;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;password=;CHARSET=utf8;";
            c1.Open();
            string Q = "select count(*) as nb from medecin,disp_medecin,disponibilite where medecin_id=med_id and disp_id=disponibilite_id and speciality_id='" + spec_id + "' and jour=" + jr + " and "+ hdeb + " between heure_deb and heure_fin and " + hfin + " between heure_deb and heure_fin";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(Q, c1);
            MySqlDataReader R = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            int nb_disp = 0;
            while (R.Read())
            {
                nb_disp = int.Parse(R.GetString("nb"));
            }
            c1.Close();

            MessageBox.Show(nb_disp.ToString());   

        }
```

The problem is :

[image: avaibilities on monday]

The query returns 1 if an avaibility in the database is similar to the avaibility that the secretary want to insert, else 0 that means he can insert it.

for example Doctor A and Doctor B are both cardiologits (same speciality),

if doctor A is available on Monday from 9:00 to 11:00, the query returns 1 if i try to make a similar avaibility for another doctor of same speciality in the same day , in the time times, BUT :

when i try to insert an avaibility for Doctor B from 8:00 to 10:00 or from 10 to 12, the query returns 0 that means that in this period i can insert this new disponibility, and that have to be undone because in this case I want that the query return 1 because the hour 10:00 is between the start hour and End hour of doctor A, that means in this situation 2 doctors of same speciality will be availalble in the same day, in the same time (10:00)!

How to interdict that? Please Help.

Comment: And what's wrong with your code?

Comment: see the problem under the code in the picture

Comment: I see your description of your requirements. What I fail to see how all these relate to your code and how you attempted to resolve the issue in the first place. At the moment this question seems to be a pure code request to me. Such questions are usually not well received here on SO.

Comment: I suggest you concentrate on the sql query only. Maybe do it step by step, then it is easier to understand what is going on. First find doctors with the same speciality, then get those doctors availability, lastly check if the new availability is totally or partly inside that availability. Verify your findings on each step. And if you are having specific challenges with the query, then you can post those questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start off with the negative bits.  I can see a LOT of problems in your framework, so let's cover the main ones:

- Why are you storing a DATETIME as a day (integer) and an hour (integer)?  Wouldn't it be much more efficient to just store these as DATETIMEs?  What does the day (jour) even represent, is this day of the month (in which case how do you handle months with different lengths, or leap years), or is it day of the week (in which case how would you book an appointment more than one week in advance)?
- This code is prone to SQL Injection, as you build up your query without protecting the parameters being added.  Yes, the data being added all comes from drop-downs, so in theory it should be controlled, but this is still extremely unsafe;
- What happens if your SQL Connection drops halfway through the method?  I would strongly suggest adding some basic error trapping, also adding some "using" blocks to allow all those objects (connection, command object, data reader) to be disposed correctly in case of failure;
- You state that your query returns 0 meaning no conflict or 1 meaning there is conflict, but this isn't the case.  It actually returns the COUNT of conflicts, so if you were to somehow allow a conflict (e.g. adding one directly to the database backend) then it would potentially return a 2, which might then not be processed correctly?

Your SQL query can be broken down to this (I reformatted it for clarity):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS nb 
FROM 
    medecin m
    disp_medecin dm ON dm.Med_id = m.medecin_id
    disponibilite d ON d.disponibilite_id = dm.disp_id
WHERE 
    speciality_id = <spec_id>
    AND jour = <jr>
    AND <hdeb> BETWEEN heure_deb AND heure_fin 
    AND <hfin> BETWEEN heure_deb AND heure_fin;
```

I have indicated where there is a parameter being added by sticking  around it.

Putting this in English I read this as:

- find the number of doctors who;
- have the speciality being requested;
- where the day being booked matches an appointment for that doctor;
- and the appointment start time intersects this appointment;
- and the appointment end time intersects this appointment.

Taking your example, where Doctor A is booked from 9-11, we allow someone to book Doctor B from 8-10, even though he has the same speciality as Doctor A because the appointment start time DOES NOT intersect with Doctor A's appointment (even though the end time does).

So I think (bearing in mind all of the above), that the fix would be simply to change this:

```
and jour=" + jr + " and "+ hdeb + " between heure_deb and heure_fin and " + hfin + " between heure_deb and heure_fin";
```

to this:

```
and jour= " + jr + " and ("+ hdeb + " between heure_deb and heure_fin OR " + hfin + " between heure_deb and heure_fin)";
```

So instead of saying that the start AND end must both intersect with an existing appointment, we are now saying that if either the start OR end time being booked intersect with an existing appointment then that's a no-go.

I could be way off track here, so let me know if this helps at all...